# variable showing in terminal instead of being appended into a file on Bash

Tags: linux, bash, variables, syntax, append

I am doing an assignment which involves in appending a variable to a file. but the output is going out in the Terminal instead of outputting in the file. Can you help me please?

This is the code

---

```
#!/bin/bash

cdate=$ date | awk '{print $2" "$3" "$4}'
IP_r=$ $cdate ifconfig ens33 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'

echo $IP_r >> /home/admin17/ip_address.log
```

---

and this is the output

```
24 Dec 23:52:25
192.168.180.131
admin17@SERVERAS:~$
```

basically i want the date and IP address in the file /home/admin17/ip_address.log

Thank you

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Either something went wrong when you posted/edited your post, or you're using a very weird shell syntax. Wherever you have `=$ $...`, you most likely had `=$\`$...` before. Better use the `$()` syntax supported by (somewhat) modern `bash`: `cdate=$( date | awk '{print $2" "$3" "$4}' )` (or even better, `cdate=$(date +'%Y%m%d')`

Comment: thank you very much for your help! IT WORKED!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cdate="$(date | awk '{print $2" "$3" "$4}')"
IP_r="$(ifconfig ens33 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}')"

echo $cdate $IP_r >> "/home/admin17/ip_address.log"`
```

If you want the output on different lines then just use \n

```
echo -e $cdate\n$IP_r >> "/home/admin17/ip_address.log"
```

> Output from ~/ip_address.log:

```
 cat ~/ip_address.log
 25 Dec 01:08:54
 192.168.1.104
```